# How to add MOV in LTspice

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, ltspice, symbol

I am using LTspice for my simulation, in that we are using MOVs and common mode coil so we are trying to do simulation for that. How can we do that? And where can I get the models for MOVs and common mode coil?

Comment: LTspice ships with an educational example showing how to use the built-in VARISTOR.  It's called `varistor.asc`.  You can make common-mode chokes using coupled inductors, similar to how you make transformers: https://ltwiki.org/files/LTspiceHelp.chm/html/Transformer_Model.htm  What specifically you're trying to model/test/measure will determine if these simple models are accurate enough for your needs.

Comment: can you please share the link of ""varistor.asc"".

Comment: MyDocuments\LTspiceXVII\examples\Educational\varistor.asc

Comment: If you're using LTspice 17.0.x, then it's in `Documents\LTspiceXVII` as described above.  However, in LTspice 17.1.x they changed a bunch of things and I don't know where they put the Educational examples anymore.